# What is taint analysis?

Tags: privacy, taint-analysis

I just came across the term "taint analysis" in a crypto-related conversation.

This came up while discussing "tracking bitcoin transactions" so it's somehow related to that. That's all I know.

Answer (score 4):

The “taint” of a Bitcoin transaction evaluates the association between an address and earlier transaction addresses. The more “‘taint” the stronger the link between the two addresses.

https://bitcoin-class.weebly.com/taint-analysis.html

Comment: More specifically, taint analysis can be used to track [dirty money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_laundering) across the Bitcoin blockchain. Its theory is however disputed.